# How to insert an image in markdown in jupyter and export as PDF

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to export a notebook to pdf via latex, but doesn't work.

If I upload an image in markdown cell,

```
![image.png](attachment:image.png)
```

I can see the image in notebook, but when I export to pdf
the final file doesn't open, it says that the file can be danified and can't be open.

But if I put the image via cell code

```
PATH = "C:/Users/my_folder/"
Image(filename = PATH + "image.png", width=800)
```

the pdf works well, but I don't like the style, with the grey box on the cell code...

Could someone help me? How to export notebooks with markdown images or how to change the style of exported files in jupyter notebook to something more similar to an article.